# Title property breaks sencha chart

Tags: javascript, extjs, charts, sencha-charts

I created a sample chart with two Y axis and after I gave the series a `title` property, it breaks the chart. It gives the following error on the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Array.prototype.indexOf called on null or undefined

If we look at the call stack, we see that this happens in the `updateTitle()` function:

[image: Error call stack]

According to the [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/#!/api/Ext.chart.series.Series-cfg-title) the series do have a title property so why does it breaks the chart?

```js
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function() {
        var chart = new Ext.create('Ext.chart.CartesianChart', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            width: 500,
            height: 500,
            legend: {
                docked: 'bottom'
            },
            "width": 740,
            "height": 440,
            "axes": [{
                "title": "Month",
                "type": "category",
                "position": "bottom",
            }, {
                "title": "Reputation",
                "type": "numeric",
                "position": "left",
            }, {
                "title": "Upvote",
                "type": "numeric",
                "position": "right",
            }],
            "series": [{
                "xField": "name",
                "yField": "data0",
                "yAxis": 1,
                "title": "Reputation gain",
                "type": "line"
            }, {
                "xField": "name",
                "yField": "data1",
                "yAxis": 2,
                "title": "Upvotes",
                "type": "line"
            }],
            "store": {
                "fields": ["name", "data0", "data1"],
                "data": [{
                    "name": "08/14",
                    "data0": 1567,
                    "data1": 2335
                }, {
                    "name": "09/14",
                    "data0": 1654,
                    "data1": 1246
                }, {
                    "name": "10/14",
                    "data0": 1777,
                    "data1": 1646
                }, {
                    "name": "11/14",
                    "data0": 2014,
                    "data1": 1456
                }, {
                    "name": "12/14",
                    "data0": 2562,
                    "data1": 2321
                }]
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to place the `title` property before the `yAxis` property in the series. So define your series like

```js
"series": [{
    "title": "Reputation gain",//Have to be placed before yAxis.
    "xField": "name",
    "yField": "data0",
    "yAxis": 1,
    "type": "line"
}, {
    "title": "Upvotes",//Have to be placed before yAxis.
    "xField": "name",
    "yField": "data1",
    "yAxis": 2,
    "type": "line"
}],
```

This is a Sencha bug I already reported in the support forum. For some reason they rely on the order of the object properties and because of that the order you place the properties into the object actually matters.